# Isolating Red/Green/Blue Channel in Java BufferedImage

Tags: java, image-processing, colors, bufferedimage, color-channel

How to isolate red/green/blue channel in BufferedImage: I have following code that does NOT work:`

```
public static BufferedImage isolateChannel(BufferedImage image,
        EIsolateChannel channel)
{
    BufferedImage result=new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(),
            image.getHeight(),
            image.getType());
    int iAlpha=0;
    int iRed=0;
    int iGreen=0;
    int iBlue=0;
    int newPixel=0;

    for(int i=0; i<image.getWidth(); i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<image.getHeight(); j++)
        {
            iAlpha=new Color(image.getRGB(i, j)).getAlpha();
            iRed=new Color(image.getRGB(i, j)).getRed();
            iGreen=new Color(image.getRGB(i, j)).getGreen();
            iBlue=new Color(image.getRGB(i, j)).getBlue();

            if(channel.equals(EIsolateChannel.ISOLATE_RED_CHANNEL))
            {
                newPixel=iRed;
            }

            if(channel.equals(EIsolateChannel.ISOLATE_GREEN_CHANNEL))
            {
                newPixel=iGreen;
            }

            if(channel.equals(EIsolateChannel.ISOLATE_BLUE_CHANNEL))
            {
                newPixel=iBlue;
            }

            result.setRGB(i,
                    j,
                    newPixel);
        }
    }

    return result;
}`
```

By isolating channel I mean that if red channel is selected for isolation, for example, that only red component of picture is shown!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Color` in java is defined in a packed integer,that is in a 32 bit integer the first 8 bits are alpha, next 8 are red, next 8 are green and last 8 are blue.

Suppose the following is an 32 bit integer representing a color.Then,

```
AAAAAAAA RRRRRRRR GGGGGGGG BBBBBBBB
^Alpha   ^Red     ^Green   ^Blue
```

That is, each of alpha, red, green and blue are basically 8 bits with values from 0 to 255 (the color range). So when you would want to combine these individual components back into the 32 bit integer color you should write

`color=alpha<<24 | red<<16 | green<<8 | blue`

So as per the rules change the code to the following

```
if(channel.equals(EIsolateChannel.ISOLATE_RED_CHANNEL))
{
    newPixel = newPixel | iRed<<16; 
    //Can also write newPixel=iRed , since newPixel is always 0 before this
}

if(channel.equals(EIsolateChannel.ISOLATE_GREEN_CHANNEL))
{
    newPixel = newPixel | iGreen<<8;
}

if(channel.equals(EIsolateChannel.ISOLATE_BLUE_CHANNEL))
{
    newPixel = newPixel | iBlue;
}
```

<sup>**Note** : I have ORed the `newPixel` before each component to allow display of multiple channels simultaneously, i.e you could display red and green with blue turned off.</sup>

---

**UPDATE**

The second  error you are getting is due to the fact that you are not resetting the value of `newPixel` after each iteration. So to fix it add the line `newPixel=0` within the loop.
Your code should be

```
newPixel=0; //Add this line
iAlpha=new Color(img.getRGB(x, y)).getAlpha();
iRed=new Color(img.getRGB(x, y)).getRed();
iGreen=new Color(img.getRGB(x, y)).getGreen();
iBlue=new Color(img.getRGB(x, y)).getBlue();
```

---

For added efficiency I would suggest using `bitshifts` for obtaining the red, green, blue, and the alpha.

```
int rgb = img.getRGB(x,y);
iAlpha = rgb>>24 & 0xff;
iRed = rgb >>16 & 0xff;
iGreen = rgb>>8 & 0xff;
iBlue = rgb & 0xff;
```

This code would run faster as it does not creates 4 `Color` objects for each pixel in the source image

Comment: Hmm, nice tutor and thank you very much, but now I load some image and when I apply a color filter, I get image filled with that color - image dissapears, I get colored rectangle (if I select red filter, I get red rectangle of image size, if I select green filter, I get green rectangle and same situation is with blue filter)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int width = bufferedImage.getWidth(), height = bufferedImage.getHeight();
Object dataElements = null;
Raster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
ColorModel colorModel = bufferedImage.getColorModel();
int red, blue, green, alpha;
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {

        dataElements = raster.getDataElements(x, y, dataElements);
        // extract colors
        red   = colorModel.getRed(dataElements);
        blue  = colorModel.getBlue(dataElements);
        green = colorModel.getGreen(dataElements);
        alpha = colorModel.getAlpha(dataElements);
    }
}
```